# How can I omit [super layoutSubviews] call for UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a very complex `UITableViewCell` subclass and I found in `Instruments` that the `[super layoutSubviews]` call consumes 5% of running time while scrolling the table view. So I tried omitting the `[super layoutSubviews]` call since I do layout of all subviews myself. It did give me a performance boost. However, I found that without the `[super layoutSubviews]` call, interactive subviews like buttons don't receive touch events anymore.

So my question is how can I omit `[super layoutSubviews]` call in my `UITableViewCell` subclass to gain the performance boost without breaking the touch events delivery to the subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tracked it down. It's because `cell.contentView.frame` is (0, 0, 320, 44) without calling `[super layoutSubviews]` and the bounds is not large enough(specifically, the height 44 is not heigh enough) to enclose all the interactive subviews. According to the doc of `-hitTest:withEvent:`:

> Points that lie outside the receiver’s bounds are never reported as
>   hits, even if they actually lie within one of the receiver’s subviews.
>   This can occur if the current view’s clipsToBounds property is set to
>   NO and the affected subview extends beyond the view’s bounds.

That's exact the case here.

Comment: I am having the exact problem. What was your final solution? Did you add back the [super layoutSubviews] or you just adjust the contentView's frame? Did you figure what else of the tableviewcell layoutsubview we should manually add?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enumerating through the subviews and setting userInteractionEnabled to YES? Still kind of a hack but if that is truly the only thing missing, it should work.

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: All pertinent subviews have their `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`.

Comment: Hmmm I wonder if that layoutSubviews call is what adds the gesture recognizers to the controls. That could be a problem - you can test that theory by enumerating the gesture recognizers on a button and seeing if it has any. The other thing you might check is if the exclusiveTouch property is set to YES on the superview (seems unlikely since the default is NO). Sorry not to have a solid answer. Good luck.